# Get the native compiler of a Linux machine

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, gnu

I am willing to do the following:

```
gcc -dumpmachine
```

Because I want to get the architecture of the machine in a GNU like so I can give it directly to the option --host of a configure script. The case is that I can execute "gcc" hoping that will be installed on the machine? Imagine that they use icc or another compiler, what would you do, there is a way to execute the native compiler? Is also possible that the gcc is set to an alternative which is not the native of the machine so I execute that command and I get a wrong architecture. By the moment I am executing gcc but I know it can fail sometimes.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such think as "the native compiler". Compiler is just a program, distributed and written by different people and vendors, each different. gcc is one compiler, icc is another, they have different options and quirks. Each compiler you need to handle separately. Each machine has it's own instruction set or many supported instructions sets (SSE, MMX ...). Hopefully you have a compiler in which you can specify which instruction sets to use while generating assembly code.

Comment: Then there is no available solution. Just hope it's going to work fine and if there is trouble solve it. Okay, if I find some canonical solution I will answer this thread. Thank you.

Comment: Use a tool like `autoconf` to generate a `configure` script and select the appropiate compiler of the target building machine. I can only recommend you this, without more information.  THIS DOESN'T WARRANT YOU'LL BE ABLE TO COMPILE CORRECTLY due to additional missing dependencies on the target host.

Comment: It's useless to use a configure script if I don't know the architecture, I can't set the "host" option, I won't be able to cross-compile.